# Radio button is not checked in ui but programmatically it is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have to work with radio input which name will be different so I need to used jquery to remove all the checked radio first and add check only by same name of input radio with matching clicked input name.

I am trying to add checked state in radio button programmatically by using jquery but it is giving an issue on ui. it is not been selected when I clicked but working on form submission.

[image]

When i clicked on first radio it will give me following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz0ym.jpg

Here is my jquery code;

```
camperElement.imageContent.on('click', camperElement.standardRadio, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            camperElement.hiddenStandard.attr('name',e.target.name);
            camperElement.hiddenStandard.val(e.target.value);
            camperElement.standardRadio.each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('name') !== e.target.name) {
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                }else{
                    $(this).prop('checked',true);
                    $(this).attr('checked','')
                    $(this)[0].checked = true;
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#important-radio").prop('checked', true);
```

Should work, are you sure $(this) is selecting the right element?

Instead of adding click listeners to the images, you can wrap the entire image into a [label](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) element

```html
<label>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  #1
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="first">
</label>
<label>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  #2
  <input id="important-radio" type="radio" name="myRadio" value="second">
</label>
<label>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  #3
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="third">
</label>
```

Comment: I have to work with radio input which name will be different so i need to used jquery to remove all the checked first and add check only by same input radio with clicked input name. Your solution is applied before as you can see in question.